# Join lines with similar first column

Tags: unix, awk

File:

```
A    20
A    35
B    13
C    14
C    49
C    58
```

Expected output:

```
A    20,35
B    13
C    14,49,58
```

I have a tab separated file as above. I want to combine lines with a comma that have the same first column. I know how to combine the lines to give me a tab separated second column, but I'd like the combined values in column 2 to be separated with a comma instead. This is the command I was using:

```
LC_ALL='C' awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{x=$1;$1="";a[x]=a[x]$0}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' input.txt > output.txt
```

I tried to change `-F'\t'` to `-F','`, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{ A[$1] = A[$1] d[$1] $2; d[$1] = ","} 
END {for (i in A) print i, A[i]}' input.txt > output.txt
```

**Explanation** :
`A[$1] = A[$1] d[$1] $2;` - will set an associated array with index `$1` and value `A[$1] d[$1] $2`. Initially it will be equal to `$2` because `A[$1]` and `d[$1]` are not defined. `d[$1]` stores output delimiter `","` .

`END` block prints the array index(unique 1st column ) and elements(`","` separated string)  in a loop.

Comment: This worked wonderfully. Would you mind explaining what you've done though? In the end, I ended up using  `awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} { A[$1] = A[$1] d[$1] $2; d[$1] = ","} END {for (i in A) print i, A[i]}'` to preserve the first tab

Comment: `for (i in A)` won't guarantee that the output will be printed in the order OP has posted.

Comment: Yes. but then `| sort -k ...` could be used

Answer (score 1):

here is another one, takes a grouped input file

```
$ awk -v OFS=, 'function pr() {if(p2) print p2; p1=$1; p2=$0}
                              {if($1==p1) p2=p2 OFS $2; else pr()} 
                END           {pr()}' file

A       20,35
B       13
C       14,49,58
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat infile
A    20
A    35
B    13
C    14
C    49
C    58

$ awk '{a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1] ",":"") $2}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' infile
A 20,35
B 13
C 14,49,58
```

Explanation:

- `a[$1]` `a` is array, `$1` is first field, used as array key/index
- `$1 in a` if array (`a`) has index, which is `$1` then we get boolean true state
- `a[$1] ","` if previous step state is true, then content of array `a` for such index will be concatenated with 2nd field, otherwise `:""` just second field, that when array has no such index.
- `for(i in a)print i, a[i]` Loop through array `a`, and variable `i` as key, 
  print array key, and value.

`a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1] ",":"") $2` Can be written as follows for better reading/understanding for beginners.

```
# if array a seen index $1 before then
if($1 in a){

   # append with existing data
   a[$1] = a[$1] "," $2

# else
}else{

   # did not see before, lets just set new data
   a[$1] = $2

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is its multiple space  and not tab

```
awk -F'[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' -v OFS=' ' '{if(a[$1])a[$1]=a[$1]","$2; else a[$1]=$2;}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i];}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do.

```
awk '{(a[$1])?a[$1]=a[$1]","$2:a[$1]=$2} END{for (i in a) print i"\t"a[i]}' infile
```